# Geolocation accept event, before success comes in

Tags: javascript, geolocation

Is there a way to catch when the user accepted the Geolocation popup? Is there an event? Usually it takes the Geolocation API a few seconds to get the location, so i want to show a loader between accepting and the success callback.

Comment: Can't you just add a function that shows the loader before `window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` and have another function that kills it in both the success and error callbacks?

Comment: No, there are also other options in the screen :\